# Оборот с "несмотря на" - что за обособленный член?

Tags: синтаксис

Оборот с "несмотря на" - это разве обособленное дополнение(так трактует вариант ЕГЭ, изданный ФИПИ)? Всегда считала его обособленным обстоятельством...

Comment: А в каком варианте так трактуется?Это всегда было и есть обстоятельство уступки, выраженное предложным сочетанием.Какой автор? Может, Вы что-то не поняли?

Comment: Полностью с Вами согласна. Но вот что в тестах предложено:

30 вариантов ЕГЭ под редакцией И.П. Цыбулько 2013 год. Вариант 3. Задание В5 - найти обособленное дополнение. Правильный ответ - предл.31: Уезжая, несмотря на уговоры матери и причитания бабки.

???

Comment: "Уезжая, несмотря на уговоры матери и причитания бабки" - это целое предложение?

Comment: Да, там парцелляция.

Comment: Предыдущее предложение:
Уезжал обратно, туда, откуда привез свой бушлат и бескозырку.
Предложение, в котором они указывают обос. дополнение:
Уезжал, несмотря на уговоры матери и причитания бабки.

Comment: Так всё-таки глагол **"уезжал"**, а не деепричастие **"уезжая"**, а то получалось крайне странно для ЕГЭ. В первом предложении у вас - уточнение.

Comment: Понятно, что в первом предложении уточнение. Но ведь разговор идет про второе... Где они там обособленное дополнение нашли? Только сбивают детей!!!

Comment: Да, вы правы.

Comment: В подобном издании 2011, 2012 года (30 вариантов, Цыбулько)подобных ляпов не было.

Answer (score 3):

Несомненно, обстоятельство. На гриф ФП не обращайте внимания. Он больше не обязателен, поэтому вовсе не гарантия качества.